# WP .htaccess removing custom filematch

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi there we have multiple Wordpress sites where lately it has decided to be much more aggressive with controlling the .htaccess file. I am trying to add the following to it:

```
<FilesMatch “sync.cgi$“>
 Satisfy Any
 Allow from all
</ FilesMatch>
```

We need this added to allow our bitbucket repository to execute the sync.cgi file using a webhook. This is a critical step in our Continous Integration configurations that makes the site track the correct GIT branch.

So back to what happens: when I set the .htaccess file to permission: 400 it very quickly sets it back to 644 and deletes this statement from it. I can only guess it deletes the file and remakes it? I have tried adding it both above and below the #BEGIN/END WordPress section, and it doesn't seem to mater.

Here is what the full .htaccess file looks like before WP deletes my edit:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=passreq
Satisfy any

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gitbucket - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<FilesMatch “sync.cgi$“>
 Satisfy Any
 Allow from all
</ FilesMatch>
```

When it deletes my change, it changes it back to this:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=passreq
Satisfy any

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gitbucket - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How can I add what I need to the htaccess file? I thought setting it to 400 would prevent WP from changing the contents?

Or do I need to modify the line "Order allow,deny" area? if so, does someone know how?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could simply set the directive in your webserver's Virtual Host configuration and not worry about overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

So it is more of a work around than a solution, but what I did was put the necessary htaccess changes in a new htaccess file in the subfolder where the cgi script resides, rather than attempting to edit the WP htaccess file. This solved the problem and now the CGI script can be accessed by bitbucket and WP can mangle the htaccess file all it wants without impacting our continuous integration setup.

That said, if anyone has a solution to actually stop WP from recreating the htaccess file and deleting changes to it, I'd love to still know.